# Javascript change dropdown list value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$('a#noday').click(function()
{ for(g=1;g<=10;g++)
var ddl = document.getElementById('daySelect_'+g);
var opts = ddl.options.length;
for (var i=0; i<opts; i++){
    if (ddl.options[i].value == ""){
        ddl.options[i].selected = true;
        break;
    }
})

$('a#wed').click(function()
{ for(g=1;g<=10;g++)
var ddl = document.getElementById('daySelect_'+g);
var opts = ddl.options.length;
for (var i=0; i<opts; i++){
    if (ddl.options[i].value == "wed"){
        ddl.options[i].selected = true;
        break;
    }
})
```

Below is my select html code

```
<select class="form-control daySelect" id="daySelect_1" name="daySelect_1">
<option value="">Select</option>
<option value="wed">Wed</option>
<option value="sat">Sat</option>
<option value="sun">Sun</option>
<option value="satsun">Sat/Sun</option>
<option value="wedsatsun">WedSatSun</option>
</select>
```

Below is my hyperlink html

```
Set all to: 
<a id="noday" href="#"><span class="label label-info">No Day</span></a>&nbsp; 
<a id="wed" href="#"><span class="label label-info">Wednesday</span></a>&nbsp;
```

I tried to click the hyperlink, but my dropdownlist selected does not change. I did try the alert to make sure my link work, and it manage to execute alert.

My [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sca1zz8d/)

Comment: have you wrapped your code inside document.ready..???

Comment: Have you tried `$('#wed')`instead of `$('a#wed')`? Because the id must be always unique on the page.

Comment: @Exception , sorry I did wrap inside document.ready , just din't paste it here

Comment: @reporter, i added jsFiddle to display my issue, tried your #wed instead of a#wed and it seems problem still persist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things. You are missing a lot of braces, you would have noticed errors in your console. You also assumed that `daySelect_` 1 through 10 existed, according to your Fiddle they might not.

```
$('a#noday').click(function() {
    for (g = 1; g <= 10; g++) { // This was missing
        var ddl = document.getElementById('daySelect_' + g);
        if (!ddl) continue; // What if there is no daySelect_10?
        var opts = ddl.options.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < opts; i++) {
            if (ddl.options[i].value == "") {
                ddl.options[i].selected = true;
                break;
            }
        } // Missing this brace too
    }
});

$('a#wed').click(function() {
    for (g = 1; g <= 10; g++) {
        var ddl = document.getElementById('daySelect_' + g);
        if (!ddl) continue;
        var opts = ddl.options.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < opts; i++) {
            if (ddl.options[i].value == "wed") {
                ddl.options[i].selected = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

[<kbd>Updated jsFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/ca3Lzpc4/)

Lastly, you might want to think about using jQuery for all of this, rather than just the DOM events. It will save you having to do so many nested for loops, for example:

```
$('a#noday').click(function() {
    $("[id^=daySelect_").val("");
});

$('a#wed').click(function() {
    $("[id^=daySelect_").val("wed");
});
```

Much neater! [<kbd>jsFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/a1ar4c74/)

Comment: I tried your jsfiddle but it seem not working, when I click on the hyperlink, the dropdown selected does not change

Comment: @user3412075 Don't know what to say - definitely works for me! What about the jQuery fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

why to write **for** loop, same can be achieved by a single line statement :)

```
      $("#daySelect_1").val("wed");
```